# Why didn't Miraz get up?

Tags: the-chronicles-of-narnia, cs-lewis, prince-caspian

In *Prince Caspian* by C. S. Lewis, the illegitimate King Miraz is challenged to a duel by the High King of Narnia, Peter Pevensie. However, during the fight, Miraz falls down and Peter steps back to let him get up (deeming it to be the knightly and chivalrous thing to do). However, Miraz does not get up. While Peter stands waiting, two of Miraz's lords (Glozelle and Sopespian) cry that Peter had done some sort of treachery and Miraz's soldiers converge on him, but one of the lords (I don't remember which) stabs Miraz in the back (literally) to make sure he is dead. Why doesn't Miraz get up in the first place? Did the lords do something to him prior? Was he just exhausted? Or did I miss some reason in the text?

Comment: I think it is implied that he expects the cries of "Treachery!" but does not expect to get stabbed literally in the back by his people.

Comment: That's a good point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems from the text like Glozelle and Sopespian rushed the field before he had a chance to rise, eager to seize the opportunity to kill Miraz.

> The Lords Glozelle and Sopespian had their own plans ready. As soon as they saw their King down they leaped into the lists crying, "Treachery! Treachery! The Narnian traitor has stabbed him in the back while he lay helpless. To arms! To arms, Telmar!" Peter hardly understood what was happening.